# how to use the "IN" of SQL to check if a value equals to ALL columns in the parenthesis

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an sql table in phpmyadmin db which has 8 columns. I want to check if 4 of them (specific 4 columns) equals to some value.
For the example, lets say the value is "abcd", and the columns names are: c1, c2, c5, c8.

I tried to do this query:

`SELECT * FROM table_name t WHERE 'abcd' IN (t.c1, t.c2, t.c5, t.c8)`

The problem is that even if ONE of the 4 columns is "abcd", I get a row result, but I want the condition to be true only if ALL the 4 columns are "abcd".

I tried also to read about `ANY` and `ALL` but I didn't think it would work.

Of course I can write the `WHERE` clause as `t.c1 = 'abcd' AND t.c2 = 'abcd'` and so on... But I want a short way (if possible) without writing the value "abcd" many times.

How can I write this query?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: I think you could use least() and greatest(), which work in most systems. But nulls are handled differently.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to focus only on the four columns (c1, c2, c5, and c8) being "abcd" and exclude any other columns you need to use the IN operator to compare the tuple (t.c1, t.c2, t.c5, t.c8) with the tuple ('abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd'). If all four values in the columns match the respective values in the tuple, the row will be returned.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  c1 VARCHAR(50),
  c2 VARCHAR(50),
  c3 VARCHAR(50),
  c4 VARCHAR(50),
  c5 VARCHAR(50),
  c6 VARCHAR(50),
  c7 VARCHAR(50),
  c8 VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO MyTable (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8)
VALUES
  ('abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', 'abcd', 'qrst', 'uvwx', 'abcd'),
  ('abcd', 'abcd', 'ijkl', 'efrg', 'abcd', 'efgh', 'efgh', 'abcd'),
  ('efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', 'qrst', 'uvwx', 'abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl'),
  ('abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', 'qrst', 'uvwx', 'efgh', 'ijkl');
```

> ```
> Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t
WHERE ('abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd') IN ((t.c1, t.c2, t.c5, t.c8));
```

| id | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | abcd | abcd | ijkl | efrg | abcd | efgh | efgh | abcd |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cSXp0UNA)

Comment: +1 to this solution because it uses `IN()` as the OP requested, and also it would utilize an index if there is a compound index on that set of columns. However, it does require the OP to write 'abcd' multiple times, which they said they didn't want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that requires writing 'abcd' only once:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name t 
WHERE 'abcd' = t.c1
  AND t.c1 = t.c2
  AND t.c1 = t.c5
  AND t.c1 = t.c8;
```

Another solution that requires you to write 'abcd' exactly twice, no matter how many columns are in the list:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name t 
WHERE 'abcd' = LEAST(t.c1, t.c2, t.c5, t.c8)
  AND 'abcd' = GREATEST(t.c1, t.c2, t.c5, t.c8);
```

If any of the columns are NULL, then there's no way they can also all be equal to 'abcd'.

These solutions don't use the `IN()` predicate as you requested, but they're pretty simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an odd request.  Usually people are more concerned about performance and effencies than a specific way of doiong something...

But what about...

```
Select * 
FROM table_name 
where replace(concat(t.c1,t.c2,t.c5,t.c8),'abcd','') IN ('')
```

Concatenate the fields we care about; replace each with empty set, check for empty set. I guess it would return a false positive if all these fields were "empty set" initially  though...

[dbfIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/K4QNNet3)

Comment: It fails if rows contains `ab` & `cd` https://dbfiddle.uk/WWiGsAcL

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
where concat(c1,c2,c5,c8) = 'abcdabcdabcdabcd'
```

You may need to use `+` or `||` depending on your specific database.

*Depending* on your data you might need to also delimit, eg

```
where concat(c1,'-',c2,'-',c5,'-',c8) = 'abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd'
```

Comment: Row may contain values `'ab' 'cdabcd' 'abcd' 'abcd'`.

Comment: It is a correct answer but my question is about an easy and short way to do it with sql commands (if possible). Eventually my goal is to use "abcd" one time and not 4 times... When I have a problem, I want to learn more options and commands, because in the future maybe it will be 40 columns and not 4, and if I need to replace the "abcd" to something else, I will need to do it 40 times in your way...

Comment: @php123 if you find you have 40 columns requiring this application of logic then you have bigger design issues! SQL operates efficiently on rows, not columns.